# Flash Message in cakephp 3 it doesn't working

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm new with cake sorry if this is a simple problem.

When i finish to save the data and i try to show a message with information about if the user is saved or could not saved , show me the next error :

Error: Call to a member function error() on a non-object
File C:\wamp\www\proyecto\src\Controller\AdministradorsController.php
Line: 76

> AdministradorsController extends AppController

```
public function add()
{
    $administrador = $this->Administradors->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $this->loadModel('Personas');
        $persona = $this->Personas->newEntity();
        $persona->rut = $this->request->data['Personas']['rut'];
        $persona->sexo = $this->request->data['Personas']['sexo'];
        $persona->nombre = $this->request->data['Personas']['nombre'];
        $persona->apellido_paterno = $this->request->data['Personas']['apellido_paterno'];
        $persona->apellido_materno = $this->request->data['Personas']['apellido_materno'];
        $persona->direccion = $this->request->data['Personas']['direccion'];
        $persona->telefono_fijo = $this->request->data['Personas']['telefono_fijo'];
        $persona->telefono_movil = $this->request->data['Personas']['telefono_movil'];
        $persona->fecha_nacimiento = $this->request->data['Personas']['fecha_nacimiento'];
        $persona->email = $this->request->data['Personas']['email'];
        $persona->comuna_id = $this->request->data['Personas']['comuna_id'];

        if(!$this->Personas->save($persona)){

             $this->Flash->error('The administrador could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        }



        $administrador = $this->Administradors->newEntity();

        $administrador->persona_id = $persona->id;

        if(!$this->Administradors->save($administrador)){

              $this->Flash->error('The administrador could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        }

        $this->loadModel('Users');
        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        $user->username = $persona->email;
        $user->password = $this->rand_passwd(6);
        $user->estado = true;
        $user->persona_id = $persona->id;
        $user->role_id = ADMIN;

        if($this->Users->save($user)){

             $this->Flash->success('The administrador has been saved.');

             return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);

        }else{
             $this->Flash->error('The administrador could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        }

    }
    $personas = $this->Administradors->Personas->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('administrador', 'personas'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['administrador']);

    $this->loadModel('Regions');
    $comunas = $this->Regions->Comunas->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('comuna', 'comunas'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['comuna']);
}
```

The data is inserting into the data base but the Flash message give me a error, sorry for my poor english and thx

Comment: it seems you are not loading the `Flash` component. In `AppController.php` in the `initialize()` method, enter `$this->loadComponent('Flash');`

Comment: Thanks you again Andre, but in 'AppController.php' I have 'loadComponent('Flash')' but I use 'loadComponent('Flash')' again in AdministradorsController in the method 'initialize()' and this time work the Flash Message. I don't know what I did for that will happen.

Comment: Edgar, loading the `Flash` component again in another controller should not be a problem. Are you extending `AppController` as such: `class AdministradorsController extends AppController`. Another issue also that could cause a problem is if you are defining `initialize()` in your `AdministratorController`, but not calling `parent::initialize()`.

Comment: Yes, that's it, I'm not calling parent::initialize() , thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are loading the `Flash` component in your `AppController`, the issue could be that you have the method `initialize()` in your `AdministratorsController` and you are not calling `parent::initialize();` in that method. It is a must for it to work so all the `helpers`, `components`, etc, that are initialized in `AppController`s `initialize()` method are transferred over.

Answer (score 4):

### [Rendering Flash Messages in cakephp 3](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/flash.html)

**In controller:**

```
<?php
    $this->Flash->error(__('Your error message'), ['key' => 'error']);
?>
```

**In View:**

```
<?= $this->Flash->render('error'); ?>
```

> In `src/Template/Element/Flash/success.ctp` change the div class to
>   `class="alert alert-success"` i.e.

```
<?php
    if (!isset($params['escape']) || $params['escape'] !== false) {
        $message = h($message);
    }
?>
<div class="alert alert-success" onclick="this.classList.add('hidden')"><?= $message ?></div>
```

> Apply the same class to `src/Template/Element/Flash/error.ctp`

Answer (score 0):

to ease the work with the Flash Messages you can use a simple notification plugin [turbo-tribble](https://github.com/ddimitrioglo/turbo-tribble)